# Copy the data from specific files and pate it in master file on a specific sheet

Tags: python, pandas

I have a folder on my pc which I clean every monday and download new attachments (3 file in total for previous month current month and next month) from outlook (I have code for that).I have one master excel file with 12 sheet: January, February, March ... December. The files I download from outlook has same names as sheet_name in master file. What I would like to do is this: I want to take a data from each outlook file and paste it on corresponding sheet. So if i have a file called December.xlsb I want to take all the data from sheet1 and paste it in master file on sheet_name December.

Master file and outlook attachments are in different directory. Preferably I would like to do it with pandas but I welcome to other solutions too.

Im not really sure how should I do or from where should I start. For sure I will need `for loop` and  `os.listdir` I guess.  Any help is appreciated

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understood what you need based on your explanation, but try to load the name of the file, like `December.xlsb`, load it into a variable and then remove the `.xlsb` from it. Then, you'll have only `December` as a string in your variable. Then, use that variable to create the sheets or anything else you need. Do that for each file in your directory.

Comment: I have file Master.xlsx (sheet names are: Jan, Feb ... Dec), every monday I download files from outlook, (3 files in total named Oct, Dec, Jan, 1 previous month, one current month, one in future). I would like to take the data from Dec.xlsb (from sheet2) and paste it in Master.xlsx file on sheet 2.

Comment: In that case, you can use a library like `pandas` or `openpyxl` to read Excel files. `pandas` makes it a lot easier to read and manipulate Excel files than `openpyxl`. Once you load your Excel sheet into pandas with `pd.read_excel()` than your Excel file will be represented by a DataFrame in pandas.

Comment: Yes, I want to use pandas but have no clue how to write code for this. I could even search the similar problem

Comment: Well, I suggest you break down your task to smaller tasks, like: read Excel, get data from Excel, save it somewhere, etc. Then, you can directly search for the things you exactly need, not searching for the whole big task that you have. This search `how to read Excel in pandas` would result in better results than `how to open 12 Excel files, parse them, save them to my Desktop and move them somewhere else`. The more specific you are, the better help you can find (this is applicable to all programming matters in general).

Answer (score 0):

As you say, pandas is a good idea for this as it is good at manipulating excel files.

Start by reading the new excel files wherever they are saved.
Then simply add the dataframe as a new sheet in the master excel workbook

```
import pandas as pd

month = input("Enter month: ")

new_file = f"C:\New Files\{month}.xlsb"
master_file = "C:\Master Files\master.xlsb"

df = pd.read_excel(new_file)

with pd.ExcelWriter(master_file, engine='openpyxl', mode='a') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=month)
```